Is RE a good place to ask about HB Gary products?
HB Gary offers tools for memory dumping and memory analysis. Some are even free. However, I have not found any questions for those tools.
Is RE the incorrect place to ask about HB Gary tools? Are those tools just not worth trying (that's opinion based, you can skip it)? Or are there accidentally no people on RE interested in those tools?

I would suggest just going ahead and asking, and seeing the response. In fact, [tag:tools] questions can be about tool comparisons, provided that you specify objective criteria on which the comparisons are to be made.

The link is dead.

See also: Is asking about reverse engineering tools on topic
